# Wildcard parameterized not accepting Object -why?

Tags: java, generics

The following example is taken from [Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Which%20methods%20and%20fields%20are%20accessible/inaccessible%20through%20a%20reference%20variable%20of%20a%20wildcard%20type?).

```
public class Box<T> {
    private T t;

    public Box(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void put(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public T take() {
        return t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box<?> box = new Box<Object>(new Object());
        Object o = new Object();
        box.put(o); // Compiler error
        o = box.take(); // ok
    }

}
```

If you look at the decompiled version put() is accepting an Object. So why the compiler is not accepting Object in put()?

```
public class Box
{

    public Box(Object t)
    {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void put(Object t)
    {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public Object take()
    {
        return t;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Box box = new Box(new Object());
        Object o = new Object();
        o = box.take();
    }

    private Object t;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the compiler's type checker, `Box<?>` is different from `Box<Object>`. A `Box<Object>` will definitely contain an object, so it's fine to call `put(Object)`. A `Box<?>` has an unknown type parameter. Unknown is different from `Object`.

It could be `Integer` for example. Calling `put(Object)` on a `Box<Integer>` would be an error. If the compiler accepted it then you could modify your program to this:

```
Box<?> box = new Box<Integer>(1);
Object o = new Object();
box.put(o);
```

And have a very clear type mismatch. Allowing the last line to compile would simply postpone the error to runtime.

In other words, generic type erasure doesn't mean the compiler is ignorant of generic types at compile time. It does its best to catch mistakes before that information is erased.